# How to use outlook mail API in ASP.Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook-restapi

I am working on a project created using ASP.Net core. I want to implement outlook mail REST API to retrieve email messages containing a particular word from the inbox of the given email account.
I didn't find any code samples to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages` API.
Can anyone provide a code sample or give some idea to make use of the above-mentioned API?

Comment: Microsoft Graph lets your app get authorized access to a user's Outlook mail data in a personal or organization account.So, before [using the Outlook mail REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), you could refer to this article to [use the Microsoft Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.After that, you could refer the mail REST API methods and send a request with the access token.

Comment: You can also refer to this article: [Read Email From Mailbox Folders Using Microsoft Graph API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-email-from-mailbox-folders-using-microsoft-graph-api/).